# How to use image-picker's customizable jquery callback options

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to use http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

The documentation section gives an example of how to use the options, but provides no example code of how to insert the callback functions.

I tried something like adding this anywhere into my  but it didn't work.

```
$( "select" ).clicked(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp(); //random execution
});
```

I realize the answer is probably obvious to anyone who is very familiar to Jquery, but I'm relatively new, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be configured like other options:

```
$("select").imagepicker({
    hide_select : true,
    show_label  : false,
    clicked: function() {
        console.log('image selected');
    }
});
```